# Prevent paragraph from adding new line (JAVASCRIPT, HTML)

Tags: javascript, java, html, output

I have a program I'm writing that will display countries and sub-county via an array of information. I've decided to include a part where instead of displaying in a text area, I just want it to display via paragraph output.

However, if the user clicks the button again, it will keep copying and pasting the output. I want to prevent this in case the user does this action
[Current Result after button is pressed multiple times ][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/enZVW.png

It displays the result multiple times if the button is clicked again.

[How I want it to look like after pressing the button multiple times][2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXqYE.png

**HTML**

```
    <input type="input" id="city"><br><br>
    <button id="button2">   <!-- Giving button an ID to be called out in our init function and add an eventlistener -->
    Show country/subcountry</button><br><br><br>
        
   <!--  <textarea readonly id="countryOut" style="overflow-y:scroll; 
    resize: none; margin-left: 2.7em; " ></textarea><br><br>  -->

   <p id = "countryOut"></p><br><br>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

````
    // display += `${sub}, ${co}\n \n`; // display subcountry, and country with new lines included for spacing
    p2.innerHTML += `${sub}, ${co}\n \n`;
    }
    
    }
    
    }

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button1"); // When country is entered, cities will display 

    button.addEventListener("click", getCountrySub); // when click event/action is performed, the function of getCountry will execute

    var button2 = document.getElementById("button2"); // when city is entered, the region, country, sub country, etc. will display

    button2.addEventListener("click", getCities); // when click event/action is performed, the function of getCities will execute
   
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`+=` sign is making duplicated texts. 
Fix this to `=` will work what you intended.

```js
// AS-IS
p2.innerHTML += `${sub}, ${co}`

// TO-BE
p2.innerHTML = `${sub}, ${co}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like the code is incomplete, assuming that this is a loop that iterates through both lists

```js
p2.innerHTML += `${sub}, ${co}`
```

Then I think you are missing a cleanup before you start the output, so before the loops start try this:

```js
p2.innerHTML = ""; // trick is here, when button is clicked clear old results, then show new information
for (const co of countries) { // Please fix to your variable names
  for (const sub of co.sub) {
    p2.innerHTML += `${sub}, ${co}`;
  }
}
```